# SQLite vacuum before android auto backup

Tags: android, sqlite, android-backup-service, vacuum

Android [Auto Backup](http://developer.android.com/training/backup/autosyncapi.html) currently has a limit of 25 megabytes.

Is there any way to perform a SQLite [vacuum](https://sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html) on databases before backup manager runs the backup jobs?

The reason for this is to keep as many users as possible within the quota.

Comment: Why not just run a periodic vacuum job on an alarm for 3 am?

Comment: sure, but i'm looking for a better solution